# How do I summon a ghast fireball in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can summon fireballs useing `/summon fireball` in the java version of Minecraft, but then I tried it in Bedrock Edition and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Fire a fireball by putting a fire charge in a dispenser and activate it with redstone.

Then teleport it (like `/tp @e[type=fireball,r=5] 5 10 5`) to where you want.